# Overriding a class as soon as it is initialised

Tags: java, overriding

Below code is overriding navigationClick in object GenObject. Is there any other way of overriding navigationClick other than extending GenObject and implementing a method override in sub - class ?

Is there a name for such a construct as below, where an override occurs when the class is initialised ?

```
GenObject go= new GenObject(){
           public boolean navigationClick(int status, int time)
            {
```

Comment: What is the question, exactly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, in order to override a method you always have to create a subclass.

What is done in your example code is called an [anonymous class](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Programming/Nested_Classes#Anonymous_Classes), but it's really just a shortcut syntax for creating a subclass. At the bytecode level, it's a class like any other, and it will have its own .class file named something like `ContainingClass$0.class`

Answer (score 3):

You can only **override** by **subclassing**. What you're doing is creating an [`anonymous`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/innerclasses.html) class.